# How to include the type libraries in a visual c++ project?

Tags: visual-c++, linker, activex, firebreath, typelib

I am working on a FireBreath project which makes a plugin application which wraps the functions of an ActiveX control. I even have the source code of the ActiveX control.

Based on a sample example provided in the FireBreath example page i coded the necessary wrapper class to wrap the Active X controls.

To call the event interfaces ,the classes and functions  of the activex control from the firebreath project, the program which i downloaded from the firebreath example page uses a statement like this to expose the activex controls type information to the  project

```
// Import the ActiveX control's typelib so we can easily call methods, etc.
// on the ActiveX control.
#import "PROGID:FBExampleCtl.xpcmdbutton" no_namespace, raw_interfaces_only$
```

But when i use something like this in my program it gives an error cannot find the type library included in the header.

So i am not able to understand how to expose the type library of the activex control to my project and also use the methods and functions defined in the type library from my program.

ps:1) I also installed Oleview to check whether the type library is avaiable in the system. From that i also tried an alternative like

```
#import "GUID of the typelibrary". But this also didnot work.
```

2) i also tried

```
#import "myrequireddll.dll"
```

and also mentioned the path to the dll in debugging environment. But the compiler still gives the same error, unable to find the file.

Comment: Always favor using the filename directly rather than hoping the compiler can find it back through the registry.  Specify the .tlb file if you have it separately or the DLL in which it is embedded.

Comment: @Hans Passant i also tried that method. But it didnot work i guess. Kindly check the second point i added at the end of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the TLB file directly in the header (.h) file using the following #IMPORT directive

`#import "C:\<PATH_TO_YOUR_TLB_FILE>.tlb" no_namespace, raw_interfaces_only`

Answer (score -1):

Check out this post on my blog [Setting up Visual Studio 2010 for MASM32 Programming](http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/category/assembly-masm32/). It speaks about setting up for MASM32 however, it shows how to add third party type libraries and include files to your project.